# c++ boost raw socket setup

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm doing some small project, trying to setup RAW socket, proof of concept program just to get socket up and running:

io.hpp:

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <net/ethernet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>


// change max length to bytes received


template <typename Protocol>
class ll_endpoint
{

private:
    sockaddr_ll sockaddr;
public:

    typedef Protocol protocol_type;
    typedef boost::asio::detail::socket_addr_type data_type;

    ll_endpoint(char* ifname)
    {
        sockaddr.sll_family = PF_PACKET;
        sockaddr.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_ALL);
        sockaddr.sll_ifindex = if_nametoindex(ifname);
        sockaddr.sll_hatype = 1;
    }

    ll_endpoint& operator=(const ll_endpoint& other)
    {
        sockaddr = other.sockaddr;
        return *this;
    }

    protocol_type protocol() const
    {
        return protocol_type();
    }

    data_type* data()
    {
        return (struct sockaddr*)&sockaddr;
    }

    const data_type* data() const
    {
        return (struct sockaddr*)&sockaddr;
    }

    std::size_t size() const
    {
        return sizeof(sockaddr);
    }

    void resize(std::size_t size)
    {
    /* nothing we can do here */
    }

    std::size_t capacity() const
    {
        return sizeof(sockaddr);
    }

    friend bool operator==(const ll_endpoint<Protocol>& e1,
               const ll_endpoint<Protocol>& e2)
    {
        return ( e1.sockaddr.sll_addr == e2.sockaddr.sll_addr );
    }

    friend bool operator!=(const ll_endpoint<Protocol>& e1,
               const ll_endpoint<Protocol>& e2)
    {
        return !(e1.sockaddr.sll_addr == e2.sockaddr.sll_addr);
    }

    friend bool operator<(const ll_endpoint<Protocol>& e1,
              const ll_endpoint<Protocol>& e2)
    {
        return e1.sockaddr.sll_addr < e2.sockaddr.sll_addr;
    }

    friend bool operator>(const ll_endpoint<Protocol>& e1,
              const ll_endpoint<Protocol>& e2)
    {
        return e2.sockaddr.sll_addr < e1.sockaddr.sll_addr;
    }

    friend bool operator<=(const ll_endpoint<Protocol>& e1,
               const ll_endpoint<Protocol>& e2)
    {
        return !(e2 < e1);
    }

    friend bool operator>=(const ll_endpoint<Protocol>& e1,
               const ll_endpoint<Protocol>& e2)
    {
        return !(e1 < e2);
    }

};


class ll_protocol
{
   public:

        typedef boost::asio::basic_raw_socket<ll_protocol> socket;
        typedef ll_endpoint<ll_protocol> endpoint;

       int type() const {
           return SOCK_RAW;
       }
       int protocol() const {
           return protocol_;
       }
       int family() const{
           return family_;
       }
       ll_protocol(int protocol, int family): protocol_(protocol), family_(family) {}
       ll_protocol(): protocol_(htons(ETH_P_ALL)), family_(PF_PACKET) {}

      private:
        int protocol_;
        int family_;

};


class IO {

    typedef boost::asio::basic_raw_socket<ll_protocol> socket;
    typedef ll_endpoint<ll_protocol> endpoint;


     public:

     IO(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, char* ifname)
     : socket_(io_context, ll_endpoint<ll_protocol>(ifname))
     {
         do_receive();
     }

  void do_receive()
  {
    socket_.async_receive_from(
        boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length), sender_endpoint_,
        [this](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_recvd) // <--- handler
        {
          if (!ec && bytes_recvd > 0)
          {
            do_send(bytes_recvd);
          }
          else
          {
            do_receive();
          }
        });
  }

  void do_send(std::size_t length)
  {
    socket_.async_send_to(
        boost::asio::buffer(data_, length), sender_endpoint_,
        [this](boost::system::error_code /*ec*/, std::size_t /*bytes_sent*/)
        {
          do_receive();
        });
  }

  private:
  socket socket_;
  endpoint  sender_endpoint_;
  enum { max_length = 9000 };
  char data_[max_length]; // change to vector?, const std::vector<uint8_t>& packet
};
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include "io.hpp"



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

 try
 {
    boost::asio::io_context io_context;
    IO s(io_context, argv[1]);
    io_context.run();
  }
 catch (std::exception& e)
 {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
 }
 return 0;
}
```

On compile I get this error:

```
io.hpp:142:56: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
  142 |      : socket_(io_context, sender_endpoint_<ll_protocol>(ifname))
      |                                                        ^
io.hpp:142:65: error: no matching function for call to ‘ll_endpoint<ll_protocol>::ll_endpoint()’
  142 |      : socket_(io_context, sender_endpoint_<ll_protocol>(ifname))
      |                                                                 ^
io.hpp:25:5: note: candidate: ‘ll_endpoint<Protocol>::ll_endpoint(const char*) [with Protocol = ll_protocol]’
   25 |     ll_endpoint(const char* ifname)
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
io.hpp:25:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided <--- but why      *thanks Useless for spotting this, however even I pass something error is the same
```

Is it a template misuse and what I am missing?

expectation is to setup socket in a similar way to https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_udp_echo_server.cpp

Comment: Please try to create a [mre], and [edit] your question to show it.

Comment: Also please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: You should at least show the source code lines, that cause the compiler error.

Comment: The output in the error message doesn't match the code you show. And the code you show should give other errors (what is the `const` doing in the `socket_` argument list?).

Comment: const is more like my attempts to find a clue, if I remove it error is the same: there is no match to find right constructor 

same error 

io.hpp:25:5: note: candidate: ‘ll_endpoint<Protocol>::ll_endpoint(const char*) [with Protocol = ll_protocol]’
   25 |     ll_endpoint(const char* ifname)
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
/io.hpp:25:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided < ---- again same thing

btw thanks for looking into this

Comment: The code you _showed_ does pass an argument, but the code quoted in the error message does not. Maybe you're not compiling the code you thought (did you save? are there multiple copies and are you looking at the right one?), but either way we can't guess what's going on if you can't show the code that matches the error.

Comment: shared full header code, I have tried to re-assemble CMake project, the error stays

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] to show us, making the question self-contained. External links might disappear or the contents might change, making the question all but useless.

Comment: added minimum main and hpp

Answer (score 0):

The member variable `sender_endpoint_` have the type `endpoint`, which is an alias of `ll_endpoint<ll_protocol>`.

The type `endpoint` is a concrete type, it's not a template. So adding template-arguments for `sender_endpoint_` makes no sense.

Just remove the template-arguments: `sender_endpoint_(ifname)`

Comment: Thanks Some programmer dude, tried this but what makes diff is changing order of members in IO:
private:
  endpoint  sender_endpoint_;  <-- goes first
  socket socket_;

AND do this

 IO(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, char* ifname)
     : sender_endpoint_(ifname), socket_(io_context, sender_endpoint_)

Original error is gone now it complains missing protocol_type I am looking further

Comment: @goodcoffee Different problem, different question. Good luck! :)

Comment: well...  agree on that however reading boost further 
sender_endpoint
An endpoint object that receives the endpoint of the remote sender of the datagram. Ownership of the sender_endpoint object is retained by the caller, which must guarantee that it is valid until the handler is called.
so I should not fill  class field , rather I need do it with initial sequence - so here we come again to the issue

Comment: Initial sequence I mean what I started with (like in boost doc) 
 IO(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, char* ifname)
     : socket_(io_context, ll_endpoint<ll_protocol>(ifname))